# Multilingual Joomla site with multiple domains

Tags: joomla-3.x, url, .htaccess-configuration, multilingual

I have Joomla site with native language system and my site looks like this:

- www.mydomain.pl
- www.mydomain.pl/en/
- www.mydomain.pl/de/
- www.mydomain.pl/se/
- www.mydomain.pl/dk/

I have domain www.mydomain.se and www.mydomain.dk

How can I rewrite my links as:

- www.mydomain.pl/se/ to www.mydomain.se
- www.mydomain.pl/dk/ to www.mydomain.dk

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a nice free plugin [Language Domains](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/languages/multi-lingual-content/language-domains) from [Yireo](https://www.yireo.com/software/joomla-extensions/language-domains), which  allows you to switch the domain-name as soon as a specific language is selected.

Each domain is bound to a language, by configuring the plugin parameters. Once enabled, the plugin detects the current domain name, checks the current language, and redirects to a new domain if needed.

You can configure the domain-bindings within the plugin parameters, such as:

> en-GB=example.co.uk
>   fr-FR=example.fr
>   de-DE=example.de
>   nl-NL=example.nl

Comment: Thanks! I tried few plugins but all them worked wrong in some way. Do you know how to configure the rest? Example, when I am on www.mydomain.pl, the rest is like www.mydomain.pl/en/. When I enter www.mydomain.se, other versions are like www.mydomain.se/en/

Comment: OK, I have just noticed that PL, SE, DK work fine but the rest not.  Associations are ok but all links lose the language ID.  When the plugin is enabled, links in menu looks like **www.mydomain.pl/nextsite/** instead **www.mydomain.pl/cz/nextsite/**

Comment: Well... I have used this plugin more than three years ago on J2.5 site, and it worked flawlessly but with just two language domains. Haven't had a need for it recently on J3 sites. Why don't you ask developers for some help? Yireo is pretty respectable name in Joomlaverse, I'm certain they will help you.

Comment: it is no more supported :(

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following to your `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^se(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.se$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^dk(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.dk$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you only have a `htaccess.txt` file, please rename it to `.htaccess`